# Passing NSString via prepareForSegue - Swift

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, segue, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to pass a string to my Modal view controller seen below, by using the prepareForSegue method. See Below:

Here is my Initial View Controller where i will present the modal view:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    
    if segue.identifier == "newProject" {
        var newProjectVC:ModalViewController = ModalViewController()
        newProjectVC = segue.destinationViewController as ModalViewController
        newProjectVC.testString = "hello"
    }
}
```

Here is my modal view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ModalViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var testString:NSString!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        println(self.testString)
    }
}
```

Here is what it looks like in storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

The problem is that it throws an exception on this line:

```
    newProjectVC = segue.destinationViewController as ModalViewController
```

I have a feeling it could be something to do with the navigation controller but am unsure, any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are right the destinationViewController is navigation controller not ModalViewController, try that:

```
let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
let newProjectVC = navigationController.topViewController as ModalViewController
newProjectVC.testString = "hello"
```

Comment: Thanks, however I seem to be getting an exception thrown again on this line now:             let newProjectVC = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as NewProjectViewController.

Comment: Please post the exception.

Comment: I've edit my post - it doesn't spit anything meaningful out in the log - just sticks to the line above.

Comment: See my edited post I use topViewController, if it will crush try: navigationController?.topViewController

Comment: Thanks, I tried both of your suggestions, but it still results in the same type of exception thrown